# tryCatch inside dplyr's mutate?

Tags: r, exception, dplyr

Is there any exception handeling mechanism in dplyr's `mutate()`? What I mean is a way to catch exceptions and handle them.

Let us suppose that I have a function that throws an error in some cases (in the example if the input is negative), for the sake of simplicity I define the function, but in real life it will be a function in some R package. Let us suppose this function is vectorized:

```
# function throwing an error
my_func <- function(x){
  if(x > 0) return(sqrt(x))
  stop('x must be positive')
}

my_func_vect <- Vectorize(my_func)
```

Now, let's suppose I want to use this function inside `mutate()`.

If this function is used inside a `mutate()`, it stops at the first error and no result is returned:

```
library(dplyr)
# dummy data
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, -1, 4, 9))
data %>% mutate(y = my_func_vect(x))
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: x must be positive.
```

Is there a way to catch the error, and do something (e.g. return an `NA`) in this case, while getting results for the other elements?

The result I expect is what would be achieved using a loop with `tryCatch()`, i.e. something along the lines of:

```
y <- rep(NA_real_, length(data$x))
for(i in seq_along(data$x)) {
  tryCatch({
    y[i] <- my_func_vect(data$x[i])
  }, error = function(err){})
}
y
# Result is: 1 NA 2 4
```

Comment: Aren't you almost there?
Use `error = function(err){NA}` in your `tryCatch` function and I believe it works. edit: Ah of course you want to use it in mutate, nevermind.

Comment: Please read my question in its entirety. The point is not returning NA when the function throws an error. But doing the tryCatch mechanism inside dplyr's mutate().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can also make use of `purrr`'s `safely()` or `possibly()` functions.

From the `purrr` help:

> **safely**: wrapped function instead returns a list with components result and error. One value is always NULL.
>
> **quietly**: wrapped function instead returns a list with components result, output, messages and warnings.
>
> **possibly**: wrapped function uses a default value (otherwise) whenever an error occurs.

It doesn't change the fact that you have to apply the function to each row separately.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# function throwing an error
my_func <- function(x){
  if(x > 0) return(sqrt(x))
  stop('x must be positive')
}

my_func_vect <- Vectorize(my_func)

# dummy data
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, -1, 4, 9))
```

#### With map:

```r
data %>% 
  mutate(y = map_dbl(x, ~possibly(my_func_vect, otherwise = NA_real_)(.x)))
#>    x  y
#> 1  1  1
#> 2 -1 NA
#> 3  4  2
#> 4  9  3
```

#### Using `rowwise()`:

```r
data %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(y = possibly(my_func_vect, otherwise = NA_real_)(x))
#> Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2    -1    NA
#> 3     4     2
#> 4     9     3
```

The others functions are somewhat more difficult to use and apply in a 'data-frame environment', as they are more suited to work with lists, and returns such.

Created on 2018-05-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I'd be interested to know why `data %>% mutate(y = map(x, ~ possibly(my_func(.), otherwise = NA_real_)))` doesn't work? It obviously isn't a straight replacement for `tryCatch`?

Answer (score 6):

You want to evaluate every occuring error individually, maybe you shouldn't use the vectorized function. Instead use `map` from the `purrr` package- which is effectively the same as `lapply` here.

Make a function to catch the error for standard use if you want NA values in the case you get an error.

```
try_my_func <- function(x) {
  tryCatch(my_func(x), error = function(err){NA})
}
```

Then use `mutate` with `map`

```
data %>% mutate(y = purrr::map(x, try_my_func))
   x  y
1  1  1
2 -1 NA
3  4  2
4  9  3
```

Or similarly, if you don't want to declare a new function.

```
data %>% mutate(y = purrr::map(x, ~ tryCatch(my_func(.), error = function(err){NA})))
```

And lastly if you Do want to use a Vectorized function, you can skip the `map` function altogether. But personally I never use `Vectorize` so I'd do it with `map`.

```
data %>% mutate(y = Vectorize(try_my_func)(x))
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was not very clear. In the example, I have written a function that I have vectorized, but my question is for the case where the function is provided by an R package, and is already vectorized with no access to the scalar function. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: I suppose you can apply the vectorized function to single element using `map` , right? The vectorized function will just give an error if even 1 of the values raises an error, so you won't be able to catch the error for single elements in the vector - I think.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right... So, to sum up (1) I have to do the exception handling out of mutate / map, (2) I have no other choice than use the vectorized function row by row :( Thanks I'll edit my question with these elements. I don't think map adds anything here though....

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowwise` to avoid need for vectorization, and use `tryCatch` directly on the function. I'm not sure how generalizable this is though.

```r
library(dplyr) |> suppressMessages()

data <- data.frame(x = c(1, -1, 4, 9))

my_func <- function(x){
  if(x > 0) return(sqrt(x))
  stop('x must be positive')
}

data |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(y = tryCatch(my_func(x), error = function(e) NA))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2    -1    NA
#> 3     4     2
#> 4     9     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

the use of Vectorize() is somewhat hacky, as your function isnt 'truly' vectorised, but pretends to be.
Therefore you would have to layer it differently to achieve the required effect. Here is a slightly drawn out example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# function throwing an error
my_func <- function(x){
  if(x > 0) return(sqrt(x))
  stop('x must be positive')
}

safe_my_func <- safely(my_func, otherwise = NA_real_)
unwrapped_safe_my_func <- function(x)safe_my_func(x)$result
unwrapped_safe_my_func_vect <- Vectorize(unwrapped_safe_my_func)

# dummy data
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, -1, 4, 9))
data %>% mutate(y = unwrapped_safe_my_func_vect(x))

# or fully inlined : 
data %>% mutate(y = Vectorize(\(x)safely(my_func, otherwise = NA_real_)(x)$result)(x))
```